# Exchange share a folder with a blocked suser

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

an employee of a company I administer was retired, so I blocked sign in. This user (UserA) has some emails that must be accessed by another employee (UserB), but UserB cannot access UserA's entire mailbox. So I instructed UserB to create and share a folder in its mailbox, so I could put there some old and new emails as required. I gave myself (Global Administrator) Read and Manage permissions to UserA mailbox, accessed it with OWA and added UserB in "Add shared folder" in the topmost folder... getting "Not possible to complete... Try again later".

I already instructed UserB to share the folder with UserA and Global Administrator, and to give "Folder visible" permission to the inbox and root folders.

Is it possible to share a folder with a user with a blocked sign-in?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried to block sign-in for my test mailbox, then open it with my global admin account via OWA, and tried to add another shared mailbox to the test mailbox, the result that is same with yours is that the shared mailbox couldn't be accessed from the block sign-in user, but my admin account could.

As said in the following microsoft docs, **`Block sign-in`** in office 365 means that the employee's access to Microsoft 365 data is blocked: **[Block a former employee's access to Microsoft 365 data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/remove-former-employee?view=o365-worldwide#block-a-former-employees-access-to-microsoft-365-data)**, it is due to design.

However, as **bjoster** said, you could convert this mailbox to a shared mailbox:
**[Forward a former employee's email to another employee or convert to a shared mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/remove-former-employee?view=o365-worldwide#forward-a-former-employees-email-to-another-employee-or-convert-to-a-shared-mailbox)**. Some points are needed to notice:

1. ***Creating a shared mailbox is the less expensive way to go because
   you won't have to pay for a license as long as the mailbox is
   smaller than 50GB. Over 50GB and you'll need to assign a license to
   it.***
2. ***If you convert the mailbox to a shared mailbox, all the old email
   will be available, too. This can take up a lot of space.***
3. ***If you set up email forwarding, only new emails sent to the former
   employee will now be sent to the current employee.***

Comment: Thank you for testing! Just one question: when you said "...the shared mailbox couldn't be accessed from the blocked sing-in user..." did you try to permit the Global Admin account to the shared mailbox as well? Did not work for me either, but if you are able to test, we can put down this option as well.

Comment: >> ***did you try to permit the Global Admin account to the shared mailbox as well?***
In your case, if the process is the following: Global Administrator(Open another mailbox) -> Retired "User A "(Add Shared Folder)-> Another Employee "User B" -> Error "Not possible to complete... Try again later", yes it is.

Comment: @acgomes Hi, i'm here to confirm the progress of your thread, is there any update? If the above info is helpful for you to fix your problem, you could mark the best answer. Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to access a Mailbox of a *disabled* user. In order to do so, you have to convert the users mailbox into a shared ressource. You can use `Set-Mailbox` to do that:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity <MailboxIdentity> -Type Shared
```

The user account for this Mailbox will stay disabled. Bonus: This will convert the Mailbox into a license free ressource.

Comment: Thank you! Makes no sense - the mailbox is fully functional, it receives email, sends... I will check the shared Mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Grant UserB Full Access to the mailbox for UserA.

the mailbox for UserA will automatically be added to Outlook for UserB if UserB is using Outlook as their email client, or UserB can access the mailbox for UserA in OWA by choosing the "Open another Mailbox" option.

Comment: "UserB cannot access UserA's entire mailbox"